# Special Products of Transpositions

Tags: combinatorics, group-theory, permutations

[**Edit.** Significantly expanded to add examples and (I hope) clarification. Feel free to skim by reading the gray boxes.]

---

A colleague asked me for insights on a collection of special permutations, but I'm afraid the topic falls a little outside of my realm of expertise. The permutations in question can be described thusly:

> Permutations (on $n$ symbols) that are a product of $n$ transpositions with the [cycle notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation#Cycle_notation) form $$(1,s_1)(2,s_2)(3,s_3)\cdots(n,s_n) \qquad\qquad (\star)$$ That is, the $i$th "factor" of the permutation exchanges the item at position $i$ with the item at position $s_i$, where we assume $i\neq s_i$.

Note that $(\star)$ is a "recipe" for a permutation, *not* the permutation's decomposition into orbits. Note also that there are $(n-1)^n$ recipes, but only $n!$ permutations of $n$ symbols. Multiple recipes give rise to the same permutation.

For instance, for $n=3$, we have $2^3=8$ recipes $(1a)(2b)(3c)$, resulting in just $3$ permutations:
$$\begin{align}
(12)(23)(31)&: 123 \to 213 \to 231 \to 132 \\
(12)(21)(32)&: 123 \to 213 \to 123 \to 132 \\
(13)(21)(31)&: 123 \to 321 \to 231 \to 132 \\ \\
(13)(23)(31)&: 123 \to 321 \to 312 \to 213 \\
(12)(23)(32)&: 123 \to 213 \to 231 \to 213 \\
(13)(21)(32)&: 123 \to 321 \to 231 \to 213 \\ \\
(12)(21)(31)&: 123 \to 213 \to 123 \to 321 \\
(13)(23)(32)&: 123 \to 321 \to 312 \to 321
\end{align}$$

More briefly:
$$132\;(\times 3) \qquad 213\;(\times 3) \qquad 321\;(\times 2)$$
where the "$(\times m)$" gives the "multiplicity" of the permutation (ie, the number of recipes $(\star)$ that result in it).

For $n=4$, we have $3^4=81$ recipes, yielding $12$ permutations:

$$\begin{align}
&1234\;(\times 3)\qquad
1342\;(\times 9)\qquad
1423\;(\times 7)\\
&2143\;(\times 11)\quad\;\;
2314\;(\times 9)\qquad
2431\;(\times 6)\\
&3124\;(\times 7)\qquad
3241\;(\times 6)\qquad
3412\;(\times 7)\\
&4132\;(\times 5)\qquad
4213\;(\times 5) \qquad
4321\;(\times 6)
\end{align}$$

For $n=5$, we have $4^5 = 1024$ recipes, yielding $60$ permutations:

$$\begin{align}
&12354\;(\times 9) \quad 
\phantom{0}12435\;(\times 9) \quad 
\phantom{0}12543\;(\times 8) \quad 
\phantom{0}13245\;(\times 9) \quad 
\phantom{0}13452\;(\times 28) \quad 
13524\;(\times 21) \\
&14253\;(\times 21) \quad
14325\;(\times 8) \quad 
\phantom{0}14532\;(\times 20) \quad 
15234\;(\times 15) \quad 
15342\;(\times 7) \quad 
\phantom{0}15423\;(\times 20) \\
&21345\;(\times 9) \quad 
\phantom{0}21453\;(\times 37) \quad 
21534\;(\times 29) \quad 
23154\;(\times 37) \quad   
23415\;(\times 28) \quad 
23541\;(\times 19) \\
&24135\;(\times 21) \quad 
24351\;(\times 18) \quad 
24513\;(\times 25) \quad 
25143\;(\times 16) \quad
25314\;(\times 14) \quad 
25431\;(\times 20) \\ 
&31254\;(\times 29) \quad 
31425\;(\times 21) \quad 
31542\;(\times 15) \quad 
32145\;(\times 8) \quad
\phantom{0}32451\;(\times 19) \quad 
32514\;(\times 15) \\
&34152\;(\times 25) \quad
34215\;(\times 20) \quad
34521\;(\times 18) \quad 
35124\;(\times 21) \quad 
35241\;(\times 14) \quad 
35412\;(\times 20) \\
&41235\;(\times 15) \quad 
41352\;(\times 14) \quad
41523\;(\times 21) \quad 
42153\;(\times 16) \quad 
42315\;(\times 7) \quad 
\phantom{0}42531\;(\times 14) \\ 
&43125\;(\times 20) \quad 
43251\;(\times 20) \quad 
43512\;(\times 20) \quad 
45132\;(\times 15) \quad 
45213\;(\times 15) \quad 
45321\;(\times 12) \\
&51243\;(\times 12) \quad 
51324\;(\times 10) \quad
51432\;(\times 17) \quad 
52134\;(\times 12) \quad 
52341\;(\times 6) \quad 
\phantom{0}52413\;(\times 15) \\
&53142\;(\times 15) \quad 
53214\;(\times 17) \quad 
53421\;(\times 18) \quad
54123\;(\times 14) \quad 
54231\;(\times 14) \quad 
54312\;(\times 12) 
\end{align}$$

And so forth.

> In the above, we get $n!/2$ permutations (which would necessarily mean: all the members of $S_n$ that match $n$'s parity), but it's not immediately obvious to me that this is always the case. (Certainly, we always get $n$'s-parity permutations, but do we always get *all* of them?) I'll point out that my colleague and I are primarily interested in even $n$ ---so that we're working within (if not with the entirety of) the alternating group, $A_n$--- but considering all $n$ may help reveal patterns.

---

Now, my colleague and I are interested in counting the number of these special permutations "with multiplicity" that move items $i$, $j$, $k$ into positions $1$, $2$, $3$ (where $n \gg 3$). For instance,

> Among the permutations of the form $(\star)$ on the (English) alphabet, how many result in $26$-letter strings beginning with a $3$-letter word of my choosing, say, "cat$\cdots$" or "dog$\cdots$"?

(More generally, how many permutations yield strings starting with a $4$-, $5$-, or $m$-letter word of my choosing?)

In terms of the permutations given above, I could ask questions like

> How many special permutations (with multiplicity) ...
>
> - ... of $\phantom{45}123$ begin with $\phantom{495}2$? Answer: $\phantom{00}3$
> - ... of $\phantom{45}123$ begin with $\phantom{49}31$? Answer: $\phantom{00}0$*
> - ... of $\phantom{5}1234$ begin with $\phantom{459}3$? Answer: $\phantom{0}20$
> - ... of $\phantom{5}1234$ begin with $\phantom{59}42$? Answer: $\phantom{00}5$
> - ... of $\phantom{5}1234$ begin with $\phantom{9}123$? Answer: $\phantom{00}3$
> - ... of $12345$ begin with $\phantom{999}3$? Answer: $217$
> - ... of $12345$ begin with $\phantom{99}15$? Answer: $\phantom{4}42$
> - ... of $12345$ begin with $\phantom{9}321$? Answer: $\phantom{42}8$
> - ... of $12345$ begin with $2431$? Answer: $\phantom{42}0$*

*The first $(n-2)$ entries in the permutation determine the last $2$ (this is clear from parity), so it's possible to specify length-$(n-1)$ beginning strings that never occur. (Not that that really matters to us. In our investigation, we want to specify beginning strings of length *far* less than $n$.)

---

If all we wanted was to know the number of ways item $i$ can move into position $j$, then a fairly straightforward analysis of products of permutation matrices would do. Here are resulting tabulations for $n=3,4,5,6$, where the $(i,j)$th element counts the number of permutations (with multiplicity) that move item $i$ into position $j$.
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 3 & 3 & 2 \\
 3 & 2 & 3 \\
 2 & 3 & 3 \\
\end{array}
\right)\qquad
\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 19 & 26 & 20 & 16 \\
 23 & 14 & 24 & 20 \\
 21 & 20 & 14 & 26 \\
 18 & 21 & 23 & 19 \\
\end{array}
\right)\qquad
\left(
\begin{array}{ccccc}
 175 & 273 & 225 & 189 & 162 \\
 229 & 138 & 252 & 216 & 189 \\
 220 & 201 & 126 & 252 & 225 \\
 208 & 204 & 201 & 138 & 273 \\
 192 & 208 & 220 & 229 & 175 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cccccc}
 2101 & 3524 & 3024 & 2624 & 2304 & 2048 \\
 2869 & 1732 & 3280 & 2880 & 2560 & 2304 \\
 2805 & 2564 & 1552 & 3200 & 2880 & 2624 \\
 2725 & 2580 & 2464 & 1552 & 3280 & 3024 \\
 2000 & 2100 & 2180 & 2244 & 1476 & 2500 \\
 2500 & 2625 & 2725 & 2805 & 2869 & 2101 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

One observes that the matrices are symmetric across the secondary diagonal. Less obviously, they indicate that there are $(n-1)^{n-1}-(n-2)^{n-1}$ ways for item $1$ to stay put, and $2(n-2)^{n-1}$ ways for item $1$ to move to position $n$. General formulas for other entries are somewhat trickier to express.

These independent tallies are one thing, but I'm at a loss for how to count "compound" circumstances, such as (in the simplest case)

> $$\text{"# of ways ( item $i$ moves to position $1$ ) AND ( item $j$ moves to position $2$ )"}$$

Of course, "brute force" enumeration ---generating all the permutations, and counting the ones we want--- already becomes computationally intractable once $n$ nears $10$. Our suspicion is that there's effectively no good solution here. That said, it seems *possible* that the specific nature of the recipe $(\star)$ provides enough structure to facilitate such enumeration, perhaps through clever recursion or exploitation of some aspect of the symmetric group, $S_n$ (or, maybe, the alternating group, $A_n$). So, before my colleague shelves this particular puzzle, I thought I'd ask for pointers here. It would even be helpful to know

> Have these "special permutations" been studied in the literature?

---

If it's true that the recipes $(\star)$ always give us half of the permutations in $S_n$, then this problem can be broken into two parts

> - Find the $n$'s-parity members of $S_n$ that begin with a specified sequence.
> - Count the number of ways a member of $S_n$ can be decomposed into form $(\star)$.

Comment: The question apears trivial on first reading, so I must be misinterpreting it.  
Firstly, the product of n transpositions, as you write it, seems to decompose the permutation into n 2-cycles, which is a permutation of 2n (not of n).  
Secondly, of all 26! permutations of the letters of the alphabet, we can fix k letters into a pre-defined position, and all (n-k) others can be freely permuted, giving (n-k)! permutations.  
Could you please give a few brute-force counts upto say n=7 and a more elaborate example on n=3 or 4 to illustrate the selection of permutations you seek to count.

Comment: @WouterM.: The transposition formula doesn't represent the permutation's decomposition into orbits. (It's possible, for instance, that the first factors are $(1,2)(2,1)$, which reduce to $(1)(2)$. So, $(1,2)$ isn't an orbit.) The transpositions simply give the "recipe" for a special permutation: Move the item in position $1$, then move the item in position $2$, then move the item in position $3$, ..., then move the item in position $n$. There are, therefore, $(n−1)^n$ recipes, which must map to some subset of all $n!$ permutations. I'll update my question to be more clear and to give examples.

Comment: Does http://oeis.org/A001710 help any?

Comment: The 'multiplicity' of the resulting permutations equals the class size of the partitions encoding their cycle structure: for n=5 I get 20 x (32) + 30 x (41) + 10 x (2111)

Comment: The partitions mentioned above are exactly those having an even number of parts.

Comment: You seem to be using "multiplicity" different than me. (To me, it's the number of "transposition recipes" $(\star)$ that give rise to a *particular* permutation; for you, it seems to mean the number of *all* resulting permutations. Be that as it may ...) Nevertheless, your calculation of the count of resulting permutations appears relevant ... although I don't see how or why you came to apply it. Could you explain and/or point me to references for appropriate results?

Comment: I just played (like you did) with the (n-1)^n permutations falling into a limited number of types, and then focussed on the underlying partitions. I got a bit of luck recognising the class sizes, but recognizing the partitions in even # of parts was easier. The hard mathematics of it is beyond me. That's why I don't pretend to 'answer' anything, I just want to play along.

Comment: Again, for n=5, *your* multiplicities are 432 x (32) + 512 x (41) + 80 x (2111) after grouping permutations by cycle structure partitions.

Comment: Two small errors: Your $(i,j)$ matrices seem to be the wrong way around -- they show the number of recipes for moving item $j$ to position $i$, not vice versa. And you have the correct count $225$ in the $(1,3)$ entry of the matrix for $n=5$, but a wrong count of $217$ for that case in the list of answers above that. (The rest of those answers are correct.)

Answer (score 1):

I don't see an analytical solution for this. Since you write that brute force enumeration becomes computationally intractable once $n$ nears $10$, I'm assuming that you're interested in a computational solution. This can easily be done by keeping track, in each of the $n$ steps, of the number of ways the items of interest could have been permuted so far. [Here's Java code](https://gist.github.com/joriki/a9fd5ea8f60ebfdfb06f) that does this. I tested it against some of your results.

The numbers of recipes for permutations of the alphabet that result in strings starting with "cat" or "dog" are $171114214080872315853377269465088$ and $226062155864710562305001318569480$, respectively. (Note that, since the code keeps track of the positions of the letters of interest, not the letters at the positions of interest, you need to use e.g. "cat" for the `from` variable and "abc" for the `to` variable.)

Comment: A year later, I get an answer. Hooray! Now, if I could only remember what exactly I was thinking when I asked ... :)

Comment: @Blue You could (should?) have asked it on Math Overflow. As it seems pretty exploratory: "Have these "special permutations" been studied in the literature?" - I guess they'll not close the question.